# Governor limits in relation to System.setPassword

Tags: governorlimits, passwords, bulkification

I can't seem to find how to bulkify `System.setPassword(Id, String)` method to set passwords for multiple users at once.

Can it be done? If not, what governor limits I might potentially hit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done :) Each call uses up 1 DML statement so you'll hit the limit of 150 (assuming of course there were no other updates etc).

In the past I've used a simple batch job that run through Users (it doesn't have to be scheduled, exposed with a button or something). If you don't want that - sth like this should be a "poor man's batch" sufficient for quick fixes?

```
String lastProcessedUsername = 'example.user@example.org.test';

List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Name, Username, Alias 
    FROM User 
    WHERE isActive = true AND Username > :lastProcessedUsername
    ORDER BY Username
    LIMIT 150
];

for(User u : users){
    System.debug('Setting password for ' + u);
    System.setPassword(u.Id, 'changeMe123');
}
```

After the script has run you take note of last shown debug statement, modify the initial variable and rerun it. Repeat until got < 150 rows.

P.S. It's a good idea to skip the System Administrator profiles in the query ;) Of course won't work with profiles with SSO enabled etc.